# Sizeof with variables in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn how to use sizeof() in C by determining the sizes of the following variables. Can someone tell me if i'm wrong or right? I'm unsure if I'm understanding the concept or not.

```
int x[] = {5, 6, 7};
float y[5];
double d;
char c[5] = {1, 2};
```

- sizeof(x): 3 --- because the array has 3 elements
- sizeof(y): 5 --- the array has 5 elements
- sizeof(d): 8 --- always the size of a double
- sizeof(c): 5 --- the array has 5 elements

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: `sizeof` always returns the size in bytes, not the number of elements (unless it's a `char` array).

Comment: sizeof() returns the size in bytes, that is for x: 3*sizeof(int). The size of doubles is implementation defined.

Comment: [The `sizeof` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof).

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof` operator gives you the number of bytes<sup>(1)</sup> an item needs to store its data, *not* the number of elements in an array<sup>(2)</sup>.

Hence, for a 32-bit integer, 8-bit character, "normal" IEEE-854 implementation (32-bit single-precision `float` and 64-bit double-precision `double`), you'll see your sizes as `12` (three `int` elements), `20` (five `float` elements), `8` (a `double`), and `5` (five `char` elements).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Keep in mind that the ISO C definition of byte is *not* necessarily an 8-bit value. Instead it's the smallest addressable item (such as a `char`). You'll find many standards documents prefer to use the term "octet" for a guaranteed-8-bit value.

Or, to put it another way, `sizeof(char)` is *always* one.

---

<sup>(2)</sup> To work out *array* sizes, you can divide the size of the whole array by the size of the first element:

```c
int xyzzy[] = {1, 2, 3};
int num_elems = sizeof(xyzzy) / sizeof(*xyzzy);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator tells you the size of its operand *in bytes*.

So assuming an `int` is 4 bytes, a `float` is 4 bytes, and by definition a `char` is 1 byte, then:

- `sizeof(x)` = 12
- `sizeof(y)` = 20
- `sizeof(c)` = 5

Answer (score 0):

others have pointed out that your understanding is wrong. But since you menton arrays in the question its worth showing you a very common c idiom

taking your

```
int x[] = {5, 6, 7};
```

you will see this

```
int xLen = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);
```

ie divide the length of the array by the size of each element in order to determine how many elements in a given array

In your case (assuming 4 bytes for an int)

```
int xLen = 12/4;
```

ie 3

Comment: You might want to point out that this sizeof "trick" only works for true arrays. Once it has decayed to a pointer it will no longer work (and that such a decay happens when passing arrays to function, even using the `[]` syntax).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah I was thinking that, but thought for a beginner that would be too much info - anyway OP if you try this trick and it doesnt work come back and reread Some Progs comment

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addendum: when you begin working with structs, padding may make `sizeof` not work the way you might expect.

```
struct A {
    char b[3];
};
```

For the above, `sizeof(struct A)` (on my machine anyway) returns `3`.

But if I add a four byte `int` to the struct:

```
struct A {
    char b[3];
    int c;
};
```

Now `sizeof(struct A)` does *not* return `7` but rather `8`.